# How to find array of object if current value more closest to now date?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have JSON file that contain year value in string in `edu_end_year`. I want to choose one if the data more than one in same `emp_id` when the `edu_end_year` is closest to date now.

here's the data:

```
educations = [
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "edu_degree": "SMA",
        "edu_end_year": 2011
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    }
]
```

here's result what i expected :

```
[
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    }
]
```

I was trying using `filter()` and `find()`, but still no luck.

please let me know if you need more information to solve that problem if it's still not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to use a `Map` and store the education with the highest `edu_end_year` for each `emp_id`.

```
const maxEducations = new Map();
for (const education of educations) {
  const maxEducation = maxEducations.get(education.emp_id);
  if (maxEducation && education.edu_end_year <= maxEducation.edu_end_year) continue;
  maxEducations.set(education.emp_id, education);
}
```

The if-statment will skip the rest of the iteration if `maxEducation` is found and the current `education.edu_end_year` less or equal to `maxEducation.edu_end_year.`

If either `maxEducation` is not set, or we encounter a new max `edu_end_year` then the current education is set as the new maximum.

Once you've iterated through all educations and you'd like to have an array of the values, you can do the following

```
const result = Array.from(maxEducations.values());
```

```js
const educations = [
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "edu_degree": "SMA",
        "edu_end_year": 2011
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    }
];

const maxEducations = new Map();
for (const education of educations) {
  const maxEducation = maxEducations.get(education.emp_id);
  if (maxEducation && education.edu_end_year <= maxEducation.edu_end_year) continue;
  maxEducations.set(education.emp_id, education);
}

console.log(Array.from(maxEducations.values()));
```

Comment: thankss!! it's work perfectly in my code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this code efficient to handle big data or not, but that's work to fix if *emp_id* is same.

**suggestion use this code after pagination**

```js
educations = [
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "edu_degree": "SMA",
        "edu_end_year": 2011
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    }
]

for (let i = educations.length -1; i > 0; i--){
    if(educations[i].emp_id === educations[i-1].emp_id){
        educations.splice(i, i)
  }
}
console.log(educations)
```

Comment: thankss for answering my question!!  :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

- use `reduce()` to loop through each element
- Check your final array (acc) has items by checking `emp_id` into list
- If it's first item then insert into
- If same `emp_id` exists then check which year is greater
- Replace newer year record into final array

```js
educations = [
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "edu_degree": "SMA",
        "edu_end_year": 2011
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 1,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "edu_degree": "S1",
        "edu_end_year": 2015
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "edu_degree": "S13",
        "edu_end_year": 2017
    },
    {
        "emp_id": 2,
        "edu_degree": "S14",
        "edu_end_year": 2016
    }
]

finalArr = educations.reduce((acc, prev) => {
  if(!acc.find(x=>x.emp_id === prev.emp_id)){
    acc.push(prev)
  }
  else{
    let record = acc.find(x=>x.emp_id === prev.emp_id);
    if(prev.edu_end_year >= record.edu_end_year){
      let index = acc.findIndex(x=>x.emp_id === prev.emp_id);
      acc[index] = prev;
    }
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(finalArr)
```

Comment: thankss for answering my question!!  :D

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
const educations = [{"emp_id": 1,"edu_degree": "SMA","edu_end_year": 2011},
    {"emp_id": 1,"edu_degree": "S1","edu_end_year": 2016},
    {"emp_id": 3,"edu_degree": "S3","edu_end_year": 2014},
    {"emp_id": 2,"edu_degree": "S1","edu_end_year": 2016}];

const res=Object.values(educations.reduce((a,c)=>{
 if(!a[c.emp_id]||a[c.emp_id].edu_end_year<c.edu_end_year) a[c.emp_id]=c;
 return a;
},{}));
console.log(res);
```

I misunderstood your question at first and changed my answer accordingly now. The above snippet uses a single `.reduce()` loop to filter out the latest elements for each `.emp_id`.

Comment: thankss for answering my question!!  :D